# Copy subset of Music library to second computer, preserving metadata?

Tags: itunes, music.app

On my primary Mac, I have a fairly large music library.  I have a secondary Mac with a smaller hard drive, so I’d like to copy just a smaller collection of my favourite music across, for listening when I’m working/travelling with that Mac.  I have the subset of my music picked out as a playlist; I have a large USB stick available; and there’s no existing Music library on the target computer that I care about preserving.

I can copy just the raw files across, via a USB stick, by selecting all the playlist songs in Music, hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (Edit > Copy), then going to the Finder and hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (Edit > Paste) in the destination folder on the USB drive; then on the target computer, importing those into a fresh Music library.

However, that loses a lot of metadata from the library (ratings, play counts, playlists, at least).  I can find plenty of instructions for copying an *entire* iTunes/Music library including metadata (and I’ve done that in the past) — but I can’t use those now, since my whole library is too big to fit on the secondary computer, let alone the USB stick.  So my overall question: **Is there a way to copy just a selected subset of a Music library from one Mac to another, retaining at least the ratings (and if possible, other library metadata)?**

I’m open to solutions involving commandline tools or scripting, if needed.  Both computers are running Ventura 13.6.3 (can’t update further, since Apple now designates >5-year-old devices as [Vintage](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624)).